# Suppress \abstract with the apa6 class?

Tags: abstract, apa6

I am currently working on a paper using the `apa6` class and I won't require an abstract, i.e. it will be worse if I have one.
Would anybody happen to know of a clean way to suppress or deactivate the abstract in an `apa6` class document? I tried to work around it, but couldn't come up with anything working.

Comment: You said that you tried a workaround. Ergo you've got some code which you can form to a [minimal example](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl) and add to your question.

Comment: From what I see from the code, the absence of an abstract will only produce a warning.

Comment: hey there, well an example won't do any good in that case, as I just tried to delete the lines that mention abstract from the class file but it resulted in errors unfortuantly.

Comment: Well seems like I was assuming that with apa6 nothing changed. the original apa style produced an error if you don't define \abstract{}. As I found out now apa6 does not. Lesson learned :)